# What does "str" + x + "str" mean?

Tags: c#, string-concatenation

Why would you use `"str" + x + "str"` in ImageLocation.

```
 private void CreateEnemies()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int x = rnd.Next(1, kindOfEnemies + 1);
        PictureBox enemy = new PictureBox();
        int loc = rnd.Next(0, panel1.Height - enemy.Height);
        enemy.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        enemy.ImageLocation = "Aliens/" + x + ".png";

    }
```

I don't understand why you would use this.

Comment: It inserts a  (random) number x into the path, so it effectively loads a random image..

Comment: You don't understand the syntax or the motivation behind using a random number to build an image path?

Comment: @Md Rakibul Islam If one of the answers solved your problem, please mark it as resolved to close this thread. If not please clarify what is still missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `+` operator is used for adding. If used on a string it will not add two strings, but concatenate them:

```
var text = "Hello" + "World" + "String";
Console.WriteLine(text); // Prints "HelloWorldString"
```

So the code above just constructs a string. Because the variable `x` is not of type int, .Net will automatically call `.ToString()`.

```
int x = 5;
var text1 = "Aliens/" + x +".png"; // is the same as below.
var text2 = "Aliens/" + x.ToString() +".png"; // is the same as above.

Console.WriteLine(text); // Prints "Aliens/5.png"
```

In C# version 6 and above you can also use string interpolation, which makes things clearer:

```
var text1 = $"Aliens/{x}.png"; // is the same as below.
var text2 = $"Aliens/{x.ToString()}.png"; // is the same as above.
```

With string interpolation, you can embed variables into a string, by placing them into curly braces.

Note that the string has to start with a `$`.

Answer (score 0):

`+` is used for [string concatenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/how-to-concatenate-multiple-strings)

Answer (score 0):

It is concatenating strings together. So "Aliens/" + *The string value of 'x'* + ".png" are being 'added' together.

Lets say:

```
int x = 1
```

The output string would be

```
"Aliens/1.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to randomize the image of the alien that you get.

Your solution has a folder called `Aliens` with files named `0.png`, `1.png`, `2.png`, and so on in it. Each file has an image of an "alien", which your program loads into a `PictureBox`. Your code picks one of these files at random, using string concatenation.

With C# 6 and newer you can use string interpolation:

```
enemy.ImageLocation = $"Aliens/{x}.png";
```